# Xamarin radio buttons not displayed with Orientation = "horizontal"

Tags: xamarin.forms, radio-button, orientation, stacklayout

Follow-on question to [xamarin radio buttons not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72970172/xamarin-radio-buttons-not-displaying).

I've created a public git repo at https://github.com/GrumpyPacker/HR to reproduce the issue.  Since the data that I'm displaying in the radio buttons is determined from a database, there isn't any guarantee that a width request of 150 will display the full string (there will be an unknown number of choices) and I'd really like to use the horizontal space instead of displaying the choices vertically.  Currently I'm only rendering UWP.

Sample:
[image: sample of solution running showing issue]

The horizontal orientation without a width request does work when the view isn't part of the navigation structure.

Thoughts, other work arounds I haven't come up with yet that might work?